# Excel finding accociated values

Tags: excel-formula

In Excel I have the following cell structure:

```
  A B C D E
1 0 1 2 3 4
.
.
.
9 4 6 5 9 0
.
.
.
```

I want a cell `A6` finds a match on line 2 for the value in `A7`. `A7` is a value between 0-4 (the range is set by line 2). Second step is to match the column with the value on line 9 and put the matching value on line 9 in `A6`.

What is have so far is this formula in cell A6:

```
=MATCH(A7;A1:E1)
```

However this solutions does not return the cell number.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to go about this. Your first inclination to use "Match" is a good one. To expand on that:

```
=Index(A9:E9; 1; Match(A7;A1:E1))
```

This will return the value on Row 9 in the column that `Match` returns.

Conversely you could use `HLookup`:

```
=HLOOKUP(A7;A1:E9;9;false)
```

This will do a horizontal lookup for the value in `A7` in the first Row of the range `A1:E9` and return the corresponding value from the same column in the 9th row down, which is row 9.